# How do I link a calculated column to a column in another list in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I have 2 lists with some common columns. I need to multiply the Calculated Sum value (of a certain column) in one list by a particular column value in another list.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The formula in a calculated site column can reference only other site columns that are in the same list or library. Therefore, when you add the calculated site column to a list or library, you must also add the site column that is referenced in the formula.

If I were you, I'd add a column where I LOOKUP the value from the List A, and then use that column for my calculated field in List B.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use use/loockup a calculated column from the list A in List B unless doing some code and create an xslt formula filtring on SP Designer